# Populate Taxonomy Term reference field in node

Tags: 8, nodes

I'm using data from JSON to create new nodes on my Drupal 8 website. So, I have a `createNode` method that create these nodes.

Here is the code I'm using

```
  protected function createNode($json) {

    foreach ($json as $row) {
      $node = Node::create(array(
        'type' => 'product',
        'langcode' => 'en',
        'uid' => '1',
        'status' => 1,
        'title' => $row['title'],
        'field_code' => $row['code'],
        'field_manufacture' => $row['manufacture'],
        'field_product_type' => $row['type'],
        'field_barcode' => $row['barcode'],
        'field_packages' => $row['packages'],
        'field_pallet' => $row['pallet'],
      ));

      $node->save();
    }

  }
```

The problem is with `field_manufacture` and `field_product_type`, those are entity reference field to taxonomy term. I'm getting term name and I need to match it in vocabulary or add it if doesn't exist.

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, find the taxonomy term id by the term name as given below.

```
function getTidByName($name = NULL, $vocab_name = NULL) {
  $properties = [];
  if (!empty($name)) {
    $properties['name'] = $name;
  }
  if (!empty($vocab_name)) {
    $properties['vid'] = getVidByName($vocab_name);
  }
  $terms = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
    ->getStorage('taxonomy_term')
    ->loadByProperties($properties);
  $term = reset($terms);
  return !empty($term) ? $term->id() : 0;
}
```

Above function will return the term id and then pass this term id to your field like

```
// Assigning the entity reference value.
if ($tid > 0) {
  $entity->set('field_example', ['target_id' => $tid]);
}
```

Comment: what if term doesn't exists?

Comment: You can use below code to create the term programmatically.  
use Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term;  
$term = Term::create(array(  
    'parent' => array(),  
    'name' => 'Term1',  
    'vid' => 'vocab_machine_name',  
))->save();

Comment: Also please check for more options   https://www.drupal8.ovh/en/tutoriels/55/create-taxonomy-term-programmatically-on-drupal-8